# The last command output in linux for reboot is not giving the uptime instead it says still running twice

Tags: linux, bash, reboot, bash-scripting, uptime

```
[root@localhost test]# last -x reboot -s -30days
reboot   system boot  5.14.0-325.el9.x Sun Mar 10 10:51   still running
reboot   system boot  5.14.0-325.el9.x Tue Mar  5 03:05   still running
```

In the above output the second reboot is showing still running but I was expecting an something like mentioned below:

```
[root@DL380G10P2U15 aishwarya]# last -x reboot -s -30days
reboot   system boot  5.14.0-325.el9.x Wed Mar  6 03:20   still running
reboot   system boot  5.14.0-325.el9.x Tue Mar  5 08:16 - 03:20  (19:03)
reboot   system boot  5.14.0-325.el9.x Mon Mar  4 01:47 - 08:16 (1+06:28)
```

In the second output the last columns (19:03) 19 hours 3 minutes and (1+06:28) 1 day 6 hours and 28 minutes is the uptime before the another reboot.

Why is there no uptime in the first output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, this one should be a comment and not an answer. Since I do not have required reputation to comment, I've leaving an answer.

You can refer to the following links to get an idea how last gets it data for that column. Here is a part of that answer which might help you get to know why it is happening.

> Thus if the system is shut down abruptly, the shut down time won’t be stored, and last will use the previous record instead. Looking at your results:

Ref1: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410734/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-10th-column-of-the-last-commands-output

Ref2: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411290/debian-two-entries-in-last-reboot-in-still-running

Comment: So is there any other command that can give me the history of reboots , shutdowns and uptime. Or any log where I can check? Or is it like if the system shutsdown abruptly then we have no records. I need this record to get the percentage of total uptime for last 30 days after reboots/shutdowns and before reboots/shutdowns. Last command gave that history of uptimes post history of reboots/shutdowns.

Comment: When your system will shutdown abruptly, due to power loss or anything, there will be no record for that. You can find the reason through the logs generated after reboo. Please have a look at [this guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/how-to-find-out-from-the-logs-what-caused-system-shutdown) to find what caused system shutdown.